# Fluent NHibernate mapping dictionary wrapper class

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to migrate an existing HMB mapping file to Fluent mapping but have come unstuck mapping the following classed (simplified).

```
public interface IThing
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    ISettings Settings { get; }
}

public class Thing : IThing { /* Interface implementation omitted */ }

public interface ISettings
{
    string SomeNamedSetting1 { get; }
    bool SomeNamedSetting2 { get; }
    int SomeNamedSetting3 { get; }
}

public class Settings : ISettings
{
    Dictionary<string, string> rawValues;

    public string SomeNamedSetting1 { get { return rawValues["SomeNamedSetting1"]; } }
    public bool SomeNamedSetting2 { get { return Convert.ToBoolean(rawValues["SomeNamedSetting2"]); } }
    public int SomeNamedSetting3 { get { return Convert.ToInt32(rawValues["SomeNamedSetting3"]); } }
}
```

We code against the interface `IThing` and access its settings via the helper properties defined on the `ISettings` interface.  The settings are stored in the database in one table called Setting that's a bunch of key-value pairs with a foreign key to Thing.

The existing mapping file is as follows:

```
<component name="Settings" lazy="false" class="Settings, Test">
  <map name="rawValues" lazy="false" access="field" table="Setting">
    <key column="Id" />
    <index column="SettingKey" type="String" />
    <element column="SettingValue" type="String" />
  </map>
</component>
```

What I'm struggling with is the component definition because I can't find the Fluent equivalent of the `class` attribute.  Here's what I have so far:

```
public class ThingMap : ClassMap<Thing>
{
    public ThingMap()
    {
        Proxy<IThing>();
        Id(t => t.Id);
        Map(t => t.Name);

        // I think this is the equivalent of the private field access
        var rawValues = Reveal.Member<Settings, IDictionary<string, string>>("rawValues");

        // This isn't valid as it can't convert ISettings to Settings
        Component<Settings>(t => t.Settings);

        // This isn't valid because rawValues uses Settings, not ISettings
        Component(t => t.Settings, m =>
        {
            m.HasMany(rawValues).
            AsMap("SettingKey").
            KeyColumn("InstanceId").
            Element("SettingValue").
            Table("Setting");
        });

        // This is no good because it complains "Custom type does not implement UserCollectionType: Isotrak.Silver.IInstanceSettings"
        HasMany<InstanceSettings>(i => i.InstanceSettings).
            AsMap("SettingKey").
            KeyColumn("InstanceId").
            Element("SettingValue").
            Table("Setting");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in the same boat, I cracked it eventually.

```
Component<Settings>(i => i.Settings, m =>
{
    m.HasMany(rawValues).
    AsMap<string>("SettingKey").
    KeyColumn("InstanceId").
    Element("SettingValue").
    Table("Setting");
});
```

Seems obvious now!